# Where should I ask a question about business of mobile apps at stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Why isn't there any site for discussing **business** of mobile apps (or something similar)? For example, I would like to ask about principles of successful mobile application.

I mean not a site for developers, but a site for mobile apps designers (interface, graphical design, market principles) and product owners.

Is it a bad idea and where should I ask the question?

Comment: There's no such site because it hasn't been proposed, folded, spindled, mutilated and approved at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can propose it at Area51.

Comment: If you're looking to ask questions about mobile app design, you can ask on either [UX Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com) (interface) or [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) (visual design) - that doesn't solve your whole problem, but it's a large chunk of your example.

Comment: OK, I have proposed: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54700/mobile-apps?referrer=j0lUfuNyORRO9oKiy9aVeQ2

Answer (score 4):

I see you've already created a proposal on Area 51, but I wanted to point out that we already have several sites that will (or should at least; AFAIK) cover part of what you're talking about.

### [User Experience (UX)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

From [the FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq):

> User Experience - Stack Exchange is for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers.

This should cover some interface questions (not all, make sure you read the full FAQ).

### [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

From the [FAQ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Graphic Design is for questions targeted toward 2D design professionals, students, and enthusiasts.
>
> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication
> - Web design
> - Layout and printing
> - Illustration
> - Digital media
> - Examples: video, Adobe Flash

Note that it also says:

> but not about..
>
> - Web site architecture and development
>   Examples: HTML that doesn't include CSS, server-side issues

This should cover some graphic design questions.

As always, if you're not sure your question will be accepted, read the sites respective FAQ and ask in chat (or create a meta question).